# C# conditional operator - Call method if condition is true else do nothing

Tags: c#

C# provides [conditional operator (?:)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) that returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. eg

`condition ? first_expression : second_expression;`

My question is can we use the same syntax to call a method when condition is true? and when condition is false then do nothing

```
 public void Work(int? val)
 {
   var list = new List<int>();

   //ofcourse line below doesn't work
   //but is it possible to call method when condition is true and else do  nothing

   val.HasValue? list.Add(val.value) : else do nothing
}
```

Comment: Why would you want that? Just use a simple `if`.

Comment: yes you can do that....

Comment: @TylerNichols that would be interesting to see how you going to pull it off... (as you can't use `?:` without assigning result to something to start with)

Comment: I can see wanting to do that if you wanted to do inline if conditional checking and setting for variables or default values but for a Method just use a simple `If condition`

Comment: Have you tried this? I think you should have made effort before asking

Comment: @BabajideApata I think he is kinda asking us if there is a wayu, and if so what is the way.

Comment: In a way that shouldn't be done.. but he did not ask if that was a good way, just if it's possible.

Comment: @Rainbolt Why does the statement that it makes much more sense to use an `if` here imply that there aren't ever uses for the conditional operator?  This simply isn't one of them.

Comment: @Rainbolt It's not just about that.  The question is asking how to execute a statement when a condition is true.  That's literally exactly what `if` does.  The conditional operator resolves to one of two values based on a condition.  He doesn't need to resolve an expression to a value, he needs to execute a statement.  There are two tools, one of which does exactly what he wants, another that does something radically different.  Just because a screwdriver isn't good a hammering nails doesn't mean it doesn't have a purpose, it just means that isn't a proper application of it.

Comment: @Servy Okay, I admit that I misread the question. OP does actually say multiple times that the else is "do nothing", and that seems to be all the OP is concerned about. I was so convinced that OP wanted to call one of two different methods using the ternary operator. Sorry for giving you a hard time. I cleaned up all of my comments.

Comment: `and also execute another statement when the condition is false` No, he has no statement to execute when the statement is false. `And just as we shorthand if-else assignments using the ternary operator` No, that's not what the conditional operator does.  It resolves to one of two values based on a boolean; it has nothing to do with assignment.  You could assign the value it produces to something, or you could do something else with it entirely.  And I didn't say that the situations aren't *similar*, merely that the conditional operator has a purpose, and this isn't it.

Comment: @Rainbolt If one *did* want to call one of two methods based on a boolean, then that's exactly what an if/else is for.  It's literally exactly what that statement does.  The conditional operator resolves an expression to a value based on a boolean.  That is somewhat similar, but it's still a very different thing.  The two operations are not equivalent; they should be used in different situations.

Comment: @Servy By that logic, we should get rid of the ternary operator altogether and just use if-else all the time.

Comment: @Rainbolt No.  The fact that you should use hammers to hammer nails and screwdrivers to screw screws doesn't mean you should get rid of hammers altogether and use screwdrivers.  If you want an expression that resolves to one of two values, then that problem is not well suited to using an if/else statement, which is why the conditional operation exists; likewise, when you want to execute one of two statements based on a boolean, that problem is not well suited to using the conditional operation, so we have an if/else.  Technically you could solve either problem using the other, but not cleanly.

Answer (score 6):

the `?:` has also been referred to as the ternary operator in the past.  Ternary, for three.  if this, then do this, else do this.

You have two expressions.  If this, do this.  This is exactly the point of an `if` statement.  You are trying to fit your case into a construct that it isn't designed for.  **Don't do this**.

Use the correct operation for the job:

```
if(val.HasValue)
{
    list.Add(val.value)
}
```

Comment: The OP has the name right.  It's the *conditional* operator, not the Ternary operator.  It is *a* ternary operator, in that it accepts three operands, just like + - * / etc. are all binary operators, as they accept two operands.

Comment: @Servy looks like they [changed the name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) after VS2010.  I still use the terms interchangeably

Comment: That page calls it the conditional operator.  It doesn't say that the name was changed.

Comment: I know this is old, but to clarify: *The conditional operator ?:, **also known as the ternary conditional operator**, evaluates a Boolean expression and returns the result of one of the two expressions, depending on whether the Boolean expression evaluates to true or false*. See [?: operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator);

*It is a ternary operator* -> @Servy Do you have examples of other ternary operators in c#? I'm curious because I haven't come across others in my day to day.

Answer (score 2):

The C# conditional operator is used to return a different value depending on the evaluation of a condition. It is not meant to be used to to be used the way you are trying to in your question. It should like be used this :

```
int test = i > 3 ? 0 : 1;
```

`test` will then equal 0 if `i` is less than (or equal to) 3, or `test` will equal 1 if 3 is greater than 3.

To do what you want you will have to use a regular `if` statement (which you can still write in one line by the way) :

```
if (val.HasValue) list.Add(val.value);
```

Comment: Thank You all for your responses. That was really good information. I asked that question in more general way to see if  I can call any method in conditional operator. But for this particular scenario  I ended up creating extension method on list that checks if value is null before adding  `public static void AddIfNotNull<TValue>(this IList<TValue> list, TValue val)
        {
            if (val != null)
            {
                list.Add(val);
            }
        }`

Answer (score 2):

The conditional/ternary operator is supposed to return a value and that very specific value must be assigned back to somewhere.

So, in that case you can do that, yes. But, it would lead to bad design.

In a regular case, one would do this:

```
int x = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

Now, lets assume AddToList() is your desired method when the condition renders to true and DoRest() is the method you want to invoke if the condition turns out to false.

In the aforementioned case, you'd end up doing something like this:

```
int result = val.HasValue? AddToList(val.value) : DoRest();
```

Now you have to rely on `result` for finding out which one has been called (if you ever need that) and it's not very expressive and doesn't point to proper code design.

If you get a tad more adventurous you'd end up with :

```
var actionToInvoke = val.HasValue ? (Action)AddToList: (Action)DoRest;
actionToInvoke();
```

In any case, none of these lead to very readable code.

So, sticking with a simple `if(val.HasValue)` would be the simplest way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

The way null conditional operator works is you have to return a value for the variable you are assigning it to. So if you would like a string value or something else other than `void` you can call the method with out any problem. But to call a `void` method you can use a delegate.

```
  delegate void DelMethod();

        void Method() { }

        void MethodTwo() { }

        private void MyMethod()
        {

            DelMethod x;

            x = condition == true ? (DelMethod)Method : (DelMethod)MethodTwo;

        }
```

Comment: While code-only answers are not forbidden, please understand that this is a Q&A community, rather than a crowd-sourcing one, and that, usually, if the OP understood the code being posted as an answer, he/she would have come up with a similar solution on his/her own, and wouldn't have posted a question in the first place. The same principle also applies further to any future readers who might be unfamiliar with the code being presented. As such, please provide context to your answer and/or code by explaining how and/or why it works.

Comment: @AlmightyR Sorry for that. I thought it was a easy an easy to understand code. Edited nonetheless.

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong; it is! (easy to understand) However, that is only true for people familiar with the programming language, principles and/or methodology being used. Which isn't everyone, or at least isn't as many people as it could be if providing a simple explanation of the code. This is one of the many reasons why code-only answers are not outright forbidden in SO, but are still unrecommended, even for basic code. =) --- Anyways, I think you could have explained better, but that's a good start. +1 for effort.